# How can I get this bash sub shell to work in Fish?

Tags: fish

I'm trying to get this command line working in Fish.

```
git show $(git log --pretty=oneline | fzf | cut -d ' ' -f1)
```

What is supposed to happen is `git log --pretty=oneline | fzf | cut -d ' ' -f1` lets you select a commit interactively from `git log` and then returns the commit hash which is passed to `git show`.

I thought Fish uses parentheses for "subcommands" but this doesn't work.

```
git show (git log --pretty=oneline | fzf | cut -d ' ' -f1)
```

It goes straight to the default output of `git show` which is the HEAD commit.

I suspect my idea of how the shell works is incorrect. Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This is the output from the pipeline

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline | fzf | cut -d ' ' -f1
3eb7a8fa09ac94cf4a76109b896f7ba58959f5a8
```

**UPDATE 2**

As answered by @faho, this is a bug in Fish.

You can workaround for now by using a tempfile

```
git log --pretty=oneline | fzf | cut -d ' ' -f1 > $TMPDIR/fzf.result; and git show (cat $TMPDIR/fzf.result)`
```

Or, more succinctly using `xargs`

```
git log --pretty=oneline | fzf | cut -d ' ' -f1 | xargs -o git show
```

Comment: Does that pipeline return more than one line of output?

Comment: It invokes `fzf` you select from the list with the enter key and it returns a single hash. I've updated the question.

Comment: that syntax looks right. Try `set lines (git log ...); echo (count $lines); git show $lines`

Comment: That doesn't work. It shows the `HEAD` commit as if `$lines` were empty. I'm wondering if `git show` is not waiting for the input from the first part?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention `$lines` is returned as 0.

Comment: It's something to do with `fzf` because if I change `fzf` for `tail -1` it does the correct thing `git show (git log --pretty=oneline | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fish issue [#1362](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1362), which is also mentioned in [fzf's readme](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#fish-shell).

There's an easy workaround: Instead of a command substitution, use `read`, like

```
git log --pretty=oneline | fzf | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | read -l answer
git show $answer
```

(fzf currently uses a tempfile in its fish bindings, but I'm working on rectifying that)

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes sense. I can workaround for now. Hoping that the bug gets fixed one day :)